# Django: How to use more than 2 Class Based Generic Views in one template

Tags: python, django

I was trying to create a web app in which a user can see other posts while updating a post. So, for that, I want to use both ListView And UpdateView together in the same template.

My Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Entry
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin


class index(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'diary/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'entries'

    def get_queryset(self):  # def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Entry.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)


class EntryUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    template_name = 'diary/update.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I don't know if I should create another view, or that there is an inbuilt functionality for this, so, it would be really helpful if you guys can help me out.

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

EDIT:

My ListView Code In views.py:

```
class index(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'diary/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'entries'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

My UpdateView in views.py:

```
class EntryUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, MultipleObjectMixin,UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    template_name = 'diary/update.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The Error, I'm getting:

```
'EntryUpdate' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps try a `MultipleObjectMixin` in your UpdateView.

You can define with this mixin `get_queryset()` and access `object_list` in the template. Check out [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#multipleobjectmixin) for more info

**EDIT**

Sure, here's a short code example:

```
# demo/models.py

from django.db import models

class Title(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```
# demo/views.py

from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.views.generic.list import MultipleObjectMixin
from demo.models import Title


class UpdateWithListView(UpdateView, MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = Title
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form_with_list'
    fields = ['title']
    object_list = Title.objects.all()

update_with_list_view = UpdateWithListView.as_view()
```

```
# my_project/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from demo.views import update_with_list_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>', update_with_list_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And the template:

`demo/templates/demo/title_update_form_with_list.html`

```
Current title: {{ object.title }}

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>

<p>All other titles:</p>

{% for title in object_list %}
<p>Title:  {{ title.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And this is what I got in the template (I had 10 "titles" in my DB, each with random character):

[image: UpdateView with MultipleObjectMixin]

**EDIT 2**
Regarding your edited question, you are missing the definition of "object_list" in your view, which is required by the `MultipleObjectMixin`.

Please note that in my code example, in `views.py`, I'm defining the `object_list` with the query that would populate the `object_list`. I believe that the error you receive is because the mixin is expecting to receive the `object_list`.

Please try adding:

```
# demo/views.py

# omitted imports


class UpdateWithListView(UpdateView, MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = Title
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form_with_list'
    fields = ['title']
    object_list = Title.objects.all() # make sure to define this with your query

update_with_list_view = UpdateWithListView.as_view()
```

If I'm not mistaken, the `get_queryset()` method is taking care of the object retrieval for the `UpdateView`, while `object_list` is relevant for the `ListView`.

Please try to add the `object_list` to your view and check if it solves the issue.

Comment: It would really be helpful if you can just help me with one more thing, in views.py where you did [object_list = Title.objects.all()], I actually want to filter the user's post, so before in the ListView, I was using this code to filter the user's post `def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)`

Comment: Sure, if I know it, I’ll share it :)

Comment: But now When I Do The Same Django gives me an error `'EntryUpdate' object has no attribute 'object_list'`

Comment: I'd be happy to see the entire view code, can you maybe edit your OP to include that code?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't replied to you soon enough,but now I've updated the question, if you want to see any more of my code, just tell me, I really appreciate you helping me out!

Comment: I have edited my answer, please take a look and see if it solves your problem. Cheers

Comment: I did tried that and it worked kinda! I also wanted to filter the ListView, on the basis of the author, but I don't know how to do so without the `get_queryset()` if I just write `object_list = Entry.objects.filter(author=request.user)`, this gives me an error, saying that `request is not defined`, how can I avoid that? And Again, Thanks for all the support!

Comment: Hey Pumi, I just wanted to thank you cause if it wasn't for you I would not have been able to solve this! I figured it out, it works perfectly fine! but it's a weird way of filtering, but still, Thanks!